# Recording audio with low kbps using recorder.js

Tags: javascript, html, audio, recording, recorder.js

I am using recorder.js The final output which i get from this code is 48khz, 1-channel (mono) mp3 file. But my requirement is 8khz, 1-channel mp3 file. How can i achieve this with the help of recorder.js

Kindly help me to resolve the issue.

https://cdn.rawgit.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs/08e7abd9/dist/recorder.js

Thanks,
Sangeetha P.

Comment: If you use this fork you can set the rate:
https://github.com/chris-rudmin/opus-recorder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an solution. There is no option to change sample rate in Recorder.js.

I have found another plugin RecordRTC. You can record in low kbps.

Set sample rates such as 8K or 16K. It records 16kHz audio file.

**var options = {
type: 'audio',
desiredSampRate: 16 * 1000
};**

https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/blob/master/simple-demos/audio-recording.html